# Pure Pursuit controller slow response for long look ahead

Tags: motion-planning, path-planning

The pure pursuit calculates the steering angle based on that equation:
$$\delta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2L\cdot \sin(\alpha)}{ld}\right)$$
Where $L$ is the wheelbase, $\alpha$ is the target angle, and $ld$ is the look-ahead distance.

But as $ld$ is bigger, the controller decreases the steering angle... When $ld$ is big, the internal term became zero and the steering angle became zero. For example, say my car has $L=1$ and its in $(0,0)$ and I have two target points $t_1=(10, 10)$ and $t_2=(100, 100)$. In both cases $\alpha=45^{\circ}$

For $t_1$: $\delta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\cdot \sin(45^{\circ})}{14.142}\right) = 5.7106^\circ$
For $t_2$: $\delta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\cdot \sin(45^{\circ})}{141.42}\right) = 0.57106^\circ$

So, even though the points have the same angle, the steering angle for $t_2$ is very weak.

What is the best practice of choosing the look ahead distance? I want it to look far, but response quickly enough. The track has limited width, too weak steering angle (like in $t_2$) makes the robot getting off track...